# Can python recognise patterns in the printed statements while printing more than one line in a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memoization

I have a function which prints a bunch of lines one after another. It takes an input of different symbols and then replaces a string obj in a list with those symbols based on an if condition.

eg:

```
original_string = ["|-----", "|-----", "|-----", "|-----", "|-----"]

my_list = ['*', '+']


def foo(my_list):
    new_string = original_string[:]
    for i in range(len(original_string)):
        # The following if condition changes often to print different patterns.
        # I've evaluated it to give an even integer for simplicity purposes
        if i % 2 == 0:
            new_string.pop(i)
            new_string.insert(i, f"|--{my_list[0]}--")
        print(new_string)


foo(my_list)
```

I get the following output:

```
['|--*--', '|-----', '|-----', '|-----', '|-----']
['|--*--', '|-----', '|-----', '|-----', '|-----']
['|--*--', '|-----', '|--*--', '|-----', '|-----']
['|--*--', '|-----', '|--*--', '|-----', '|-----']
['|--*--', '|-----', '|--*--', '|-----', '|--*--']
```

> My question is this: How can I can have a python program recognise what output patters were generated and take action accordingly?

WHAT I AM LOOKING FOR IS SOMETHING LIKE THIS:

This is My actual code output:

```
Output pattern I want to recognise:

Pattern A:
    1 |-------x------------
    2 |-----------------x--
    3 |-----------------x--
    4 |-----------------x--
    5 |-------x------------
    6 |--------------------


Actual Final Output pattern:

1 |-------3------------------------8--------10------12
2 |-------3---------5--------------8------------------
3 |-----------------5---------7---------9-----------12
4 |--2--------------5-----------------------10------12
5 |-------3---------5---------7-------------10--------
6 |-------3------------------------8--------10------12

So, if Pattern A exists within final output, I should only print position of pattern A in the output and x should be replaced by the fret position numbers as found in the actual output.
```

Required output would look something like this:

```
    1 |-------3------------
    2 |-----------------5--
    3 |-----------------5--
    4 |-----------------5--
    5 |-------3------------
    6 |--------------------
```

Note: One position here is 5 char. i.e, "--x--" is one position

Comment: I don't understand why my question is downvoted. Is it not a valid question or is it not following some protocol?

Comment: I can see several possibilities: (1) "is there any way...?" is a strong indication of an ill-formed question.  You're on a general-purpose computer that is just short of a Turning machine.  Since the basic information is obviously in your data, the answer is 'yes'.  "How do I do it" is off topic for most issues.  (2) Lack of effort.  Your description strongly implies a look-up table, but you haven't tried to implement that.  (3) Overly verbose description.  Remember that stated central purpose of this site.  (4) Lack of research.  Memoization is a well-known technique.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like guitar tablature. Is your pattern really a list of frets to play over time, to be superimposed over the lines?

Comment: @chepner Yes, I am trying to get a guitar tabulature printed out and recognise chord shapes ^_^ Finally, someone who knows what I am doing. I have all the notes from the scale being printed on a 22 fret neck, but donno how I can filter out the notes based on left hand shapes as and when it is needed.

Comment: @Prune Thank you. I am a beginner, self taught, non graduate and I have no idea Look up table exists. I am aware of memoization but I wouldn't be able to implement it here successfully. The question is a bit Verbose yes, coz I am trying my best to explain the problem here. And It's definitely not something I haven't tried to solve myself or do some research on. I asked coz I couldn't get an explanation anywhere else. Not coz I am lazy to try and solve the problem myself. Very discouraging when question gets downvoted and closed after all the efforts that went into building the question.

Comment: @Cres, can you explain why line 3 does not continue having X at position 8 and why line 5 & 6 does not continue having X at position 3. Also why does line 6 not have X at position [-3]. Does each line remember the pattern from previous and include the patter from the input to generate the output? Or does each line come with a pattern that it needs to cross check first? Trying to understand the pattern so I can explore solutions with you

Comment: Thank you @JoeFerndz The output actually represents notes on a guitar fretboard if you can imagine one. And they change with each musical key. So, the x marks in Pattern A are the left hand finger positions on the fret board which remains in same shape, but only the position across the fretboard changes. Each line is independent of previous lines.  I updated my question, so hopefully, it makes more sense now. Please let me know if not. I can give you all the info I can

Comment: Thanks for the problem clarification.  This is simply too broad for Stack Overflow; we're not a wholesale system design site.  Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: @Prune Yes, I do understand the problem is quite broad. I do appreciate the efforts and glad to have this amazing platform here. Maybe I'll post this question sometime after I learn more and find a better way to phrase things. Thank you ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the crux of this problem, your input will be a fret board with stopped positions marked (the ones with a digit holding the string).  You want to identify a stored chord within this board.

You're focusing in the wrong area.  Why do you want to recognize the output form?  That's a bunch of characters for human convenience.  To make this a reasonable application, you have to abstract the qualities of each chord, and store *that* in a fashion that's easier to match to a similarly abstracted fret board.

As you've said, the parameter of any match is the starting fret: how far do you need to "capo" the chord to get a match.  Think of this as a lattice on the Cartesian plane.  (0,0) is your "Capo" fret just off the "top", on an imaginary string 0 (above string 1, the high E), the upper-left corner of your diagram.  Now, your example chord, Amaj, is anchored at the high-E, 1st fret, represented by five lattice points by (fret, string) pairs:

```
[ (0, 1),
  (2, 2),
  (2, 3),
  (2, 4),
  (0, 5) ]
```

Now, the translation of this to any fret `f` is

```
[ (f+0, 1),
  (f+2, 2),
  (f+2, 3),
  (f+2, 4),
  (f+0, 5) ]
```

... and *that* is the pattern you want to find, `for f in range(12)`, perhaps.

Keep a list of those fret-point patterns, perhaps a dict with chord labels.

- Write an input function to reduce a 6-line fret board to a matrix of points.
- Write an output function to render a result into the desired 6-line form, as in your 3+5 Amaj example.
- Write a matching function to iterate through the stored chords.  For each chord, slide it from fret 0 up to your practical limit, looking for an instance where all of the points match the input board.

Comment: This is the most useful response I've got regarding this question! Thank you so much. I did think there must be better ways to do it other than trying to make sense of the output I am getting. Love the fact that you understand where I was trying to get at with the 'capo' the chord thing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  This is called "memoization".  You maintain a persistent dict of the input arguments (keys) and the output (value).  Every time you call the function, you first check to see whether that argument series has been seen before.

You can look up the @memoize decorator, and also look up the term in conjunction with "dynamic programming".

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've used memoization before with recursive calls. I believe this answer is very close to what I need. The thing is, the actual code is far more complex to explain here. I'll edit my question further

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code that would work for you.

```
xString = '''--x---------x---------x----x---------x---------x----x---------x---------x---------x----x---------x----x----x--
--x---------x---------x----x---------x---------x----x---------x---------x---------x----x---------x----x----x--
--x---------x----x---------x---------x---------x----x---------x---------x---------x----x---------x----x----x--
--x----x----x---------x---------x----x---------x---------x----x----x---------x----x----x---------x------------
--x---------x---------x---------x----x---------x---------x----x---------x---------x----x----x---------x-------
--x---------x---------x----x---------x---------x---------x----x---------x---------x----x---------x----x-------
--x---------x---------x----x---------x---------x----x---------x---------x---------x----x---------x----x----x--'''    
print(xString)
print('The pattern for this are :')

for x in xString.split('\n'):
    for i in range(0,len(x),5):
        if x[i:i+5] == '-----':
            print ('-----',end='')
        else:
            a = i//5
            if a > 9: print (f'--{a}-',end='')
            else: print (f'--{a}--',end='')
    print ()
```

The output of this code will be:

```
--x---------x---------x----x---------x---------x----x---------x---------x---------x----x---------x----x----x--
--x---------x---------x----x---------x---------x----x---------x---------x---------x----x---------x----x----x--
--x---------x----x---------x---------x---------x----x---------x---------x---------x----x---------x----x----x--
--x----x----x---------x---------x----x---------x---------x----x----x---------x----x----x---------x------------
--x---------x---------x---------x----x---------x---------x----x---------x---------x----x----x---------x-------
--x---------x---------x----x---------x---------x---------x----x---------x---------x----x---------x----x-------
--x---------x---------x----x---------x---------x----x---------x---------x---------x----x---------x----x----x--
The pattern for this are :
--0---------2---------4----5---------7---------9----10--------12--------14--------16---17--------19---20---21-
--0---------2---------4----5---------7---------9----10--------12--------14--------16---17--------19---20---21-
--0---------2----3---------5---------7---------9----10--------12--------14--------16---17--------19---20---21-
--0----1----2---------4---------6----7---------9---------11---12---13--------15---16---17--------19-----------
--0---------2---------4---------6----7---------9---------11---12--------14--------16---17---18--------20------
--0---------2---------4----5---------7---------9---------11---12--------14--------16---17--------19---20------
--0---------2---------4----5---------7---------9----10--------12--------14--------16---17--------19---20---21-
```

Comment: Thanks Joe, will use this up to clean up my code and make it a bit more compact.